# Can't select from dropdown with jQuery on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

I have a jQuery function that finds an element in an HTML select menu by its value and selects it  ([see the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w68ordrx/1/)):

```
$(function () {
    var select = $("#selectElement");
    var option = $("#selectElement option:contains('SERV')");
    option.attr("selected", "selected");
    option.siblings('option').removeAttr('selected');
    select.trigger("change");
    alert($("#selectElement :selected").text());
});
```

HTML:

```
<select data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="true" data-shadow="false" id="selectElement">
    <option id="o1" value="o1v">null</option>
    <option id="o2" value="o2v">MAIN</option>
    <option id="o3" value="o3v">MN VL</option>
    <option id="o4" value="o4v">MTRST</option>
    <option id="o5" value="o5v">SERV</option>
    <option id="o6" value="o6v">STA</option>
    <option id="o7" value="o7v">TRANS</option>
</select>
```

On Chrome in Windows 7, this works fine and the selection has been changed to "SERV" as expected. But on Chrome in an iPad, the dropdown's default value "null" is still selected, so nothing has happened.

Using jQuery's `val()` does nothing whatsoever, in either platform.

I don't think it's anything like the script being loaded at the wrong time; if I put alerts in asking about the values of `select` and `o`, those look fine.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Just in case, did you try placing the function inside $(document ).ready() http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: In our actual code, it runs inside `$(document).on("pageshow")`. Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up making a different solution entirely, but I did notice that this was (once again) probably the culprit:

```
$(function () {
    ...
})();
```

I forgot those closing parentheses again.